ADF GoogleBigQuery V2 Connector throwing error in copy data 'Error Occurred when reading' despite successful connection
we have a azure data factory that loads in data from google analytics to a azure sql db and we're currently upgrading the connector as the older one is being depreciated in October.
I've switched the linked service from using credentials stored on a self hosted IR via a file path to storing a json connection string in key vault. The connection test is successful and I can preview the data in the source section of copy data. However when running debug I get the following error message:
Failure happened on 'Source' side.

Type=Microsoft.DI.Connector.GoogleBigQuery.ExceptionUtils.GoogleBigQueryConnectorException,Message=Error
occurred when reading, ErrorCode:
UnknownError,Source=Microsoft.DI.Connector.GoogleBigQuery,''Type=System.InvalidOperationException,Message=No
current element is available.,Source=Grpc.Core,

Has anyone successfully upgraded theirs and if so did you encounter this as well?
I've tried setting up a new pipeline and creating it from scratch but no luck. Given the connection is successful I wasnt expecting an error on the source side and I cant seem to find any other documentation on a similiar error.

The issue it turned out with this was that there was an empty results set in the BigQuery. In the old legacy version of this, the adf pipeline would complete with no errors, transfer no data (common thing when you have change tracking..). Now for whatever reason the pipeline will fail if there is no data at source
